# Should I use RefCell<Rc<T>> or Rc<RefCell<T>> for a tree with parents which can be mutated?

Tags: tree, rust, reference-counting, interior-mutability

I want to implement a tree whose node has `parent` field using Rust. From the official guide [adding-a-reference-from-a-child-to-its-parent](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-06-reference-cycles.html#adding-a-reference-from-a-child-to-its-parent), they use the structure

```rust
struct Node {
    value: i32,
    parent: RefCell<Weak<Node>>,
    children: RefCell<Vec<Rc<Node>>>,
}
```

To use an instance of `RefCell<Rc<T>>` mutably, I can call `.borrow_mut()`.

In the [doc of `std::cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/index.html#introducing-mutability-inside-of-something-immutable), `let shared_map: Rc<RefCell<_>> = Rc::new(RefCell::new(HashMap::new()));` is used to introduce mutability to `Rc`.

If I want a tree with parents which can be mutated, which one is recommended?

Comment: `RefCell<Rc>` has more strict borrowing control: you can get only one mutable reference on data. `Rc<RefCell>`, allows having many mutable references at a time. So for your case `RefCell<Rc>` is better.

Comment: @Zefick What if T is a struct and I want to change some fields of T in RefCell<Rc<T>>? Am I supposed to use RefCell<Rc<RefCell<T>>>?

Comment: Yes because in this case, you have two independently mutable entities - counted reference to T and T itself, Each of this needs its own `RefCell`.